# Selected columns in sub query(Multiple column) are not showing

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery, mysql-workbench

```
select daf.id as affiliate_id,daf.name as affiliate_name,
dal.name as allocation_name,dal.id as allocation_id,dal.allocation,dal.price
from degreeamerica.affiliates daf join degreeamerica.allocations dal
JOIN(select pap.lead_price,pap.live,pap.allocation_id,pap.affiliate_id from paul.affiliates_price pap) pafp on (dal.id=pafp.allocation_id and daf.id=pafp.affiliate_id) order by daf.id;
```

pap.lead_price,pap.live,pap.allocation_id,pap.affiliate_id 
These columns are not showing in result set. Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Add `,pafp.lead_price,pafp.live,pafp.allocation_id,pafp.affiliate_id` to the end of your `Select` just before `From`

**Suggestions**

```
SELECT
    daf.id AS affiliate_id,
    daf.name AS affiliate_name,
    dal.name AS allocation_name,
    dal.id AS allocation_id,
    dal.allocation,
    dal.price,
    pap.lead_price, -- add the fields you want from paul.affiliates_price
    pap.live,
    pap.allocation_id,
    pap.affiliate_id 
FROM
    degreeamerica.affiliates daf 
    JOIN degreeamerica.allocations dal -- what are we joining on?
    -- why create a subquery with no filters? just join to table.
    JOIN paul.affiliates_price pap ON dal.id=pap.allocation_id 
        and daf.id=pap.affiliate_id
ORDER BY
    daf.id
```

Answer (score 1):

add those column in parent select statement..
like

```
select daf.id as affiliate_id,
       daf.name as affiliate_name,
       dal.name as allocation_name,
       dal.id as allocation_id,
       dal.allocation,
       dal.price,
       pafp.lead_price,
       pafp.live,
       pafp.allocation_id,
       pafp.affiliate_id 
       from degreeamerica.affiliates daf JOIN 
            degreeamerica.allocations dal JOIN
            (select        
                 pap.lead_price as lead_price,pap.live as live,
                  pap.allocation_id as allocation_id,
                  pap.affiliate_id  as affiliate_id
                 from paul.affiliates_price pap
            ) pafp on dal.id=pafp.allocation_id and daf.id=pafp.affiliate_id  
         order by daf.id;
```